# What to do about old, off topic questions that still have value?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

This question I ask is regarding a particular Q&A here: [Python: check whether a word is spelled correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500752/python-check-whether-a-word-is-spelled-correctly). This is an old question, which by today's standards would be off topic (source request) or too broad. However, it is still quite a useful question (since 20,000 people have clicked on it).

Unfortunately [most](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501551/4909087) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527067/4909087) [its](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4500865/4909087) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501041/4909087) are also link-only or VLQ. That is the nature of such questions I suppose, it just can't be helped.

My first instinct would be to flag these answers, which I did. The flags were marked helpful, but the answers were not deleted. I assume whichever moderator reviewed the flags decided the answers were too "valuable" to be deleted.

I propose some ideas for curating this post, in decreasing order of preference:

1. delete off topic answers (not all of them are off topic, thankfully), and possibly move them to comments
2. lock the post (this could also be done in conjunction with the first option)
3. delete the question entirely (bad idea, but I've seen it done before)

What would be the best course of action in this situation?

Comment: Ah, the first link was pointing to an answer. Fixed that.

Comment: Closing is not deleting, and still prevents new answers from being added. Imo closing is a good option for this post. That way, people can still view the question and it's answers. This can be done in conjunction with deleting or flagging off-topic and VLQ answers.

Comment: 4. Downvote posts that are not helpful anymore.

Comment: From [the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18973596) to the answer you originally linked to, it got 4 delete votes and 2 looks okay votes. I'm not sure how many it's supposed to take, but if it's still in review, it might just need another vote or something to delete it.

Comment: @DavyM I already mentioned that the flags were marked helpful. Meaning the consensus was to delete, but a moderator overruled it. I raised these flags over a week ago.

Comment: Oh okay I wasn't sure how that last step to delete or not worked, thanks for explaining :)

Comment: Oh the adorable naïvenessity of that question. Just for thinking there is "a simple function" that returns `True` or `False` for the correctnessness of any word.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ a moderator didn't overrule anything. They got marked helpful as the review concluded as "recommend deletion" - however, since the posts were positively scored - a further automatic flag is raised for a moderator to review if they should be deleted (only mods can remove positively scored answers anyway). Since upvoted answers aren't likely to be so problematic (in leiu of red flags etc...) that they require immediate attention and *immediate deletion*... they can linger around for a little bit. We will get to them though when the more serious *beep* is handled.

Comment: Note that just because a post has 20k views doesn't mean 20k different people have looked at it.  There's lots of automated programs hitting it, like web crawlers, or people hitting it multiple times, etc.  It might correlate to number of people seen, but fairly loosely.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to lock every single closed question that doesn't merit deletion.  Locks are designed to be a last resort brought out when all other hope is lost.  If people keep reopening the question even though it's off topic, or keep deleting it even though the community generally considers it of considerable value *then* you can start considering locking; we're not there yet.

Comment: @Servy Okay, thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I suppose the best course of action would be to just close it and leave it be. I still feel the link-only answers could be removed/moved to comments.